# Spring data - MySQL what is the order of the table lock for this query?

Tags: java, mysql, database, spring, spring-data

An example query looks like this:

```
INSERT INTO Adventure (sword, fighter, quest)
SELECT Swords.id, Fighters.id, Quests.id
FROM swords Swords, fighters Fighters, quests Quests 
WHERE Swords._id = Quests.id AND Fighters._id = Quests.id and Swords.length > 100
```

What exactly is the order of the table locks of mysql? are they all got locked together or one by one?

P.S - I'm using Spring Data repositories for my update queries. (If that's relevant in any way)

Comment: Why would anything get locked here? Can you elaborate on why you think a lock occurs?

Comment: I have a more complex query on my real project that uses Insert With Select and I receive tons of deadlocks since its running. when i look at the innodb status i can see it is involved in the deadlock

Comment: Great, now that we know you use InnoDB, it would be great to show the whole query + isolation levels that you have set up. Also, you are using an extremely old style of joining, is there any chance you would be open to changing how you perform the `SELECT` so it's more efficient and readable?

Comment: This is a query i found on the internet the original one is too messy for SO, Does one actually be able to know let alone MANIPULATE the order of locks just by refactoring the query string?